# Dependency Jar not referring to its own application.properties

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I created 2 spring boot applications.

I used 1 of these jars in the other as a dependency.

Now, both these applications have their own db configurations in their **application.properties** file respectively.

But when I run the parent project and access classes which use the dependency jar.

The properties defined in the dependency project are not found and the dependency project refers the parent project's (application in which the dependency is used) application.properties file.

How can I make the dependency maven project to use its own application.properties file.

Comment: I am no Spring boot expert, but I guess that Spring boot applications are not meant to be used as dependencies.

Comment: You mean 1 Spring Boot Application cannot be used in another as dependency? And why is that?

Comment: A Spring expert might correct me, but usually, you write a jar either as application or as library. If you have two applications which need some common code, you can write a library that is used as dependency in both of them.

Comment: Runnable Spring Boot jars cannot be used as normal jars anymore.  Look inside to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using these dependencies as normal jars, you are probably misunderstanding the way classloaders work.

At any given time you can consider all files provided by the jars on the classpath to be thrown in together in a single large pool (scope/namespace).  This mean that if you have TWO "application.properties" files from two different jars, only one of them will be visible.

You need to rethink your deployment scheme so your dependencies does not bring in their own "application.properties" files but they are baked in as part of your deployment packaging.

Comment: Can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: Have a maven module responsible for generating the final product.  Only have applications.properties provided by that, and nowhere else.  Make your product fail instantly if a property is missing.

Comment: But what about the DB configurations which are different in both applications? I will have to configure multiple DB configurations which is quite unnecessary because one jar is dependency and independent of the application which is using it.

Comment: First of all write your application so entries can be provided/overridden externally - this is what everyone else does.  If that doesn't work for you, consider each DB configuration a finished product which require it's own application.properties and hence its own maven module.   Strongly consider revising your attitude towards "quite unnecessary" because you are just starting to feel the pain of a single jar having multiple responsibilities.